# Why does PHP Storm Plugin "Jira Browser" need WebServicesPlugin enabled?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, jira, phpstorm

For a few weeks, maybe after an update, I am not able to edit my jira tickets in PHPStorm anymore. As soon as I click something like `start task` my whole IDE freezes and I've to kill it.

`Jira Browser` plugin is marked with red color in plugin settings with (hover) message "Plugin was not loaded. Required Plugin "WebServicesPlugin" is not enabled."

But I can not find any `WebServicesPlugin` that I could enable. Nor can I find something in internet about such a plugin.

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jira Browser](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/230?pr=idea) plugin is very old and not compatible with most recent PHPStorm version. 
You can try using [Atlassian Connector](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2190?pr=idea)  plugin instead - it's more up-to-date. But note that this is a third-party plugin not maintained by jetbrains (this is also true for Jira Browser

Comment: Awww... do you know if Atlassian is working on an up to date Jira Browser for PHP Storm? I'll give this connector a try, thanks.